# Scrapping facebook with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want scrap every date of card this page

```
https://www.facebook.com/events/search?q=Parties&sde=AbrQ9KopLfqYT7heXVVCxznkZYxRr9hU1JA4cdLbJhjgs56yyeHW3e833A9dGP1WlEHOyagjWyFL9Y79gw-Ko1iVuJCILVkpVsHkmSbBFb3SEA&filters=eyJmaWx0ZXJfZXZlbnRzX2NhdGVnb3J5OjAiOiJ7XCJuYW1lXCI6XCJmaWx0ZXJfZXZlbnRzX2NhdGVnb3J5XCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxODIxOTQ4MjYxNDA0NDgxXCJ9IiwiZmlsdGVyX2V2ZW50c19jYXRlZ29yeToxIjoie1wibmFtZVwiOlwiZmlsdGVyX2V2ZW50c19jYXRlZ29yeVwiLFwiYXJnc1wiOlwiXCJ9IiwicnBfZXZlbnRzX2xvY2F0aW9uOjAiOiJ7XCJuYW1lXCI6XCJmaWx0ZXJfZXZlbnRzX2xvY2F0aW9uXCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxMDg1NjA0MDI1MDgxNDFcIn0ifQ%3D%3D
```

I have This request

```js
document.querySelector('.x193iq5w' + '.xeuugli' + '.x13faqbe' + '.x1vvkbs' + '.x10flsy6' + '.x1nxh6w3' + '.x1sibtaa' + '.x1s688f' + '.xzsf02u').innerText;
```

I scrape just the first date. How can I get them all back? A `forEach`? a `querySelectorAll`? I already tried both ways but I couldn't, but I'm probably doing it wrong

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = "link fb";

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });


    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 1000,
    })

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.x193iq5w' + '.xeuugli' + '.x13faqbe' + '.x1vvkbs' + '.x10flsy6' + '.x1nxh6w3' + '.x1sibtaa' + '.x1s688f' + '.xzsf02u').innerText;
    });
    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: `I already tried both ways` please show what you tried so we can help you to debug it. SO is not here to write code for you. I would assume that you need to recursively create a list of all the URLs which require scraping and make requests to them. Also note that the string concatenation in the selector is redundant.

Comment: ```const url = "link fb"
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 1000,
    })
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.x193iq5w' + '.xeuugli' + '.x13faqbe' + '.x1vvkbs' + '.x10flsy6' + '.x1nxh6w3' + '.x1sibtaa' + '.x1s688f' + '.xzsf02u').innerText;
    });
    console.log(data);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your question, as code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, it's ok i just did it

Comment: an idea maybe ? @RoryMcCrossan